# How to read sms list from blackberry device 10 using c++

Tags: blackberry-10

can you please tell me how to read sms (test message ) inbox in blackberry 10.i used message folder api.in my device there are 6 sms . but it show zero when debug.here is my code

```
void Testmesagges::inboxSmsTest(){
     fprintf(stderr,"*****in*******\n");
      qDebug() << "***************Thegtf  is************************* ";
              bb::pim::message::MessageService messageService;
               bb::pim::account::AccountService accountService;


            //Get the SMS/MMS account
            QList<Account> accountList = accountService.accounts(Service::Messages,"sms-mms");
             fprintf(stderr,"*****count*******\n");
             qDebug() << accountList.count();
             fprintf(stderr,"*****Length*******\n");
            qDebug() << accountList.length();
            AccountKey accountId;
            if(accountList.count()>0){
             accountId = accountList.first().id();
            qDebug() << "***************The  is************************* ";
                      fprintf(stderr,"*****ID*******\n");
                       qDebug() << accountId;



             QList<MessageFolder> folders = messageService.folders(accountId);
             fprintf(stderr,"*****size*******\n");
            qDebug() << folders.size();
             fprintf(stderr,"*****count*******\n");
            qDebug() << folders.count();
             fprintf(stderr,"*****length*******\n");
            qDebug() << folders.length();
            MessageFolder firstFolder = folders.at(0);
             qDebug() << firstFolder.isValid();
             qDebug() << firstFolder.name();
            }
}
```

Comment: Here error is display

Comment: Fatal: ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range", file c:/bbndk/target_10_0_9_1673/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qlist.h, line 469